# continue statement is skipping further iterations

Tags: c#

if internalCounter and counter are 0 and Model contains 6 items , then why it's not show other properties of models except than property at index 0

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
   if(internalCounter == counter)
   {          
      continue;
   }
   <tr><td>@item.teamName</td><td>@item.W</td><td>@item.L</td></tr>
   internalCounter = internalCounter+1;
}
```

Comment: Well how do you expect either `internalCounter` or `counter` to change in the next iteration?

Comment: outside the foreach loop there is another foreach loop , counter is incremented for that , and both the counters become zero at the start of their iterations

Comment: @{
int counter = 0;
int internalCounter;
foreach (var mainIteration in Model)
{
    internalCounter = 0;
    
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
               
               if(internalCounter == counter)
               {
               continue;
               }
            }
 
    
            counter = counter + 1;
}
}

Comment: above is the full code

Comment: Please don't put code in comments. Edit it into your question - but then think about that inner foreach loop... it will run *all* the iterations without ever changing `internalCounter` or `counter` after it's hit that first `continue` statement...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better if we could see the outer loop too... but anyway:

Once your internalCounter reaches the value of counter, it never incremented (in the inner loop, so always your if () will be true.

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
   if(internalCounter != counter)
   {          
      <tr><td>@item.teamName</td><td>@item.W</td><td>@item.L</td></tr>
   }
   internalCounter = internalCounter+1;
}
```

or honoring the masters (Brian W. Kernighan, Dennis M. Ritchie):

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
   if(internalCounter++ == counter)
   {          
       continue;
   }
   <tr><td>@item.teamName</td><td>@item.W</td><td>@item.L</td></tr>
}
```

Answer (score -5):

```
if(internalCounter == counter)
{
     continue;
     <tr><td>@item.teamName</td><td>@item.W</td><td>@item.L</td></tr>
     internalCounter = internalCounter+1;
}
```

Comment: no that's totally wrong , have a look on the code , i pasted in the comment of my answer